# BindingList with IList<T> DataSource, Element Order

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, ilist, bindinglist

Can I assume that the order of the elements from an `IList<T>` remains equal, when I use it as a `DataSource` of a [`BindingSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.datasource.aspx) (Windows Forms), so that `BindingSource.Position` and `List.IndexOf()` are equivalent on the same object?

This is important to me, as `Find` is not supported on lists that are no `BindingList`, so I use the plain old `IList.IndexOf` method to determine the position of an element:

```
myBindingSource.Position = myItemList.IndexOf(myItem);
```

Apparently this works fine. But I don't know whether I could not figure out yet whether I can actually depend on this to work. I'm a bit worried, because the `BindingList`'s `List` property copies the data into new list structures (see the [`DataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.datasource.aspx) remarks)...

Cheers, Matthias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `IList<T>` should keep the same ordering at all times.  It's a step beyond `IEnumerable<T>` (in terms of additional functionality) which does not guarantee ordering, just the ability to enumerate over the collection.  `IList<T>` adds indexing to support more functionality such as `.IndexOf()` and `.RemoveAt()` which requires indexing.

Now, whether or not the data source from which you populate your `IList<T>` returns items in the same order, that's another story.

Comment: Thanks, David. I populate the DataSource from the `IList<T>` (not vice versa). Not sure if I described this precisely or misunderstood you. I'm sorry for that. Thanks anyway, so you think I should not rely on Index and Position being equivalent?

Comment: @Mudu: Maybe I'm not sure where you're looking for the immutability of indexing.  But basically, once a given implementation of `IList<T>` (assuming the implementation itself isn't broken) is instantiated, any given element within it will have the same index throughout the life of that object.  (Unless, of course, you add/remove elements.)

Comment: Ouch, fatal typo in my original question: `BindingSource`, not a `BindingList` (corrected above). I was not sure if the `DataSource` property messes up the element order, as the data is (I suppose) copied from my list to an `IBindingList` before being exposed to bound controls. However, these are both lists, so I'm confident now that they will keep the order, just as you wrote above. :)